# Querying RelatedManager objects

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-related-manager

I have models such as

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    f1 = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    f2 = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True)
    f3 = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True)

class Model2(models.Model):
    x = models.ForeignKey(Model1)
    f4 = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True)
    f5 = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True)
```

and my `admin.py` reads

```
class Model2Inline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Model2
    search_fields = ('f5',)
    extra = 1
class Model1Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('f1', 'f2')
    search_fields = ['f1']
    inlines = [Model2Inline]
```

I wish to filter Model1 based on specific values of the field `f4`

Something like

`results = Model1.objects.filter(where f4 = "some_specific_value")`

which is intended to result a query set containing instances of Model1 in which inline Model2's will have `f4` set to `some_specific_value`

Thanks!

Comment: Did you search the doc before asking ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a substitue for reading the doc

Answer (score 0):

this should work (edited, thanks to @DanielRoseman for pointing out what I was missing):

```
results = Model1.objects.filter(model2_set__f4="some_specific_value")
```

You could also give the `ForeignKey` attribute a `related_name` keyword argument, so that you can reference `Model2` from `Model1` by a more understandable name than `model2_set`.

See documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#related-objects

Comment: I already tried that but it shows me an error saying `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'Model2_set' into field.`

Comment: @AbhijitGhate - thanks, this really should have been included in the original question, because it's the most obvious way to do this, and the error is (to me, at least) unexpected. I can't immediately think why that would be happening, but I'm sure someone else here could help!

Comment: You need to use the *lower-cased* name of Model2. This would be clearer if you used actual model names, and showed actual code and errors.

Comment: thanks @DanielRoseman, can't believe I missed that (a combination of the fact that I haven't used Django in nearly a year, and normally use an all-lowercase `related_name` anyway). I'll edit the answer

Comment: @DanielRoseman  I just tried that too.  But the error still persists.